# iOS: WebThread crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, crash, web-thread

I am getting a crash in the "WebThread", but I can't understand what it is about.

NOTICE: On the "*App Transport Security Settings*", I have set all these 3 to YES: *Allow Arbitrary Loads*, *Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content*, *NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia*

How can I understand the reason?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Crazy, the crash was solved after restarting the phone